# XAML - ListViewItem - IsEnabled Binding

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-8, microsoft-metro, winrt-xaml

Please put me out of my misery:

```
<ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
    <Style TargetType="ListViewItem">
        <Setter Property="IsEnabled" Value="{Binding MyBoolField}" />
    </Style>
</ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
```

Where `MyBoolField` is a property available on each item in the `ListView`'s assigned `ItemsSource`, and is of course of type `bool`.

The desired behaviour is that the `IsEnabled` property of each `ListViewItem` is bound to the `MyBoolField` property of the object it contains (an element from the `ListView`'s `ItemsSource`). The example above however pays no attention to this binding and is always `true`.

If I set the value to `false` statically, the item becomes disabled as expected.

I can only assume this is an issue of scoping, or a restriction on the use of bindings in this particular scenario, however I am unable to find any documentation to support this.

Perhaps it is useful to know that bindings set up in the `DataTemplate` assigned to this `ListView`'s `ItemTemplate` all work okay, so the problem is hopefully not that fundamental/stupid.

### Points from the Comments

- There is no relevant output in the debug 'Output' window.
- Binding the `MyBoolField` property elsewhere works fine, as such the underlying data source is providing a Boolean value correctly and this seems to be solely an issue of binding it in this context.

Comment: Is the class containing MyBoolField properly implementing INotifyPropertyChanged?

Comment: Check for binding errors in the Output window of Visual Studio when debugging.

Comment: @Jay No errors in the Output window.

Comment: @DJ Just did - seems to have had no effect.

Comment: Of general use may be that the getter seems never to be invoked on MyBoolField, so it would seem the Setter doesn't invoke the binding whatsoever.

Comment: Can you please explain the question bit more. Normally you want that if MyBoolField = false the list view item should be disabled but from your question it seems that you are trying to acheive something different.

Comment: @DJ I have re-worded my question, hopefully this helps.

Comment: Just to make sure the style itself is working. Can you set the ToolTip, Header or any Color to a hardcoded value, which definetly must work, to see if the style is properly applied?

Comment: @dowhilefor Statically defined styles do indeed take effect as expected.

Comment: @jstephenson ok my finaly idea is: Its not the XAML its the code. Can you show as your class, at least with the property itself?

Comment: The debugger's output gives details about failed bindings - e.g. on which class the property "MyBoolField" is expected to be. If it's not the item class, try binding to RelativeSource.Self.

Comment: @dowhilefor Binding to MyBoolField elsewhere - for example within the ItemTemplate - works fine, so I am sure it is solely an issue of binding in this context.

Comment: @HDWProduction There is no indication of a problem in the debugger output. It is as if the binding is ignored entirely.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, reading [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11857505/how-do-i-do-bindings-in-itemcontainerstyle-in-winrt) it seems that its a known limitation of WinRT, maybe you find something useful there.
One thing i would also try, because the OP in that post said something regarding that is. Using a `Self` binding, and use `Path=DataContext.MyBoolField`

Further reading, this is a limitation from Silverlight, which WinRT was build upon. So [this](http://blog.xyzzer.me/2011/10/26/workaround-for-binding-not-supported-on-stylesettervalue-in-silverlight/) is a workaround which should also work for WinRT