# How to get dependency property by name in Windows Runtime?

Tags: windows-runtime, winrt-xaml

I need it to implement binding in setters.

Or are there any other workarounds to be able to set binding in style setters for Windows runtime?

Comment: You can't use a binding in a Setter. You can however modify the Template to use a binding, or add an Attached Property to apply the binding.

Comment: Are there any examples? I found an example for Silverlight but wasn't able to adapt it because I can't get DependecyProperty by name

Comment: I just saw the Filip's answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11857505/how-do-i-do-bindings-in-itemcontainerstyle-in-winrt

Answer (score 0):

What kind of binding?

e.g.

```
<Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="{ThemeResource TextControlBorderThemeThickness}"/>
```

Ok, then you should do something like this:

Here you can't bind a value to Padding.

```
<Style x:Key="GridViewItemStyle" TargetType="GridViewItem">
    <Setter Property="Padding" Value="0"/>
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="GridViewItem">
                <GridViewItemPresenter Padding="{TemplateBinding Padding}" 
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

You can bind it that way:

```
<Style x:Key="GridViewItemStyle" TargetType="GridViewItem">
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="GridViewItem">
                <GridViewItemPresenter Padding="{Binding PaddingValue}" 
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

Comment: <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="{Binding SomeValue}"/>