# binding ListBox to ObservableCollection in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, binding, listbox, observablecollection

I have a Class named Layer2Info

```
    public class Layer2Info
{
    public ObservableCollection<totalAvailablePorts> availableClientPorts = new ObservableCollection<totalAvailablePorts>();
}
```

The totalAvailablePorts Class is

```
    public class totalAvailablePorts : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public int _portID;
    public Boolean _isSelected;

    public int portID
    {
        get { return _portID; }
        set { _portID = value; NotifyPropertyChanged("portID"); }
    }
    public Boolean isSelected
    {
        get { return _isSelected; }
        set { _isSelected = value; NotifyPropertyChanged("isSelected"); }
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    private void NotifyPropertyChanged(String propertyName)
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
        {
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }
    public override string ToString()
    {
        return string.Format("{0}", portID);
    }
}
```

The creation of the data in availableClientPorts is:

```
            for (int i = 1; i <= 3; i++)
        {
            totalAvailablePorts newPort = new totalAvailablePorts();
            newPort.portID = i;
            newPort.isSelected = false;
            layer2InfoConfig.availableClientPorts.Add(newPort);              
        }
```

Now, in my MainWindow I'm binding the ListBox to the Layer2Info.availableClientPorts like this:

```
clientPortsList.ItemsSource = layer2InfoConfig.availableClientPorts;
```

and last is my xaml:

```
<ListBox x:Name="clientPortsList" 
         SelectionMode="Extended" 
         DisplayMemberPath="{Binding Path=portID}" 
         SelectedValuePath="{Binding Path=isSelected}" 
         Height="50"/>
```

Now, i'm able to see all the ports (1-3) in the ListBox, but what I want to do is that on every line that I select in the ListBox, I want the isSelected value in the availableClientPorts to change to true, and I have no idea where to start.
Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, [`SelectedValuePath`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.primitives.selector.selectedvaluepath%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) isn't what you think. [MSDN says](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.primitives.selector.selectedvaluepath%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) it "Gets or sets the path that is used to get the `SelectedValue` from the `SelectedItem`." So when the user selects an item, the `clientPortsList` will take that property of its own `SelectedItem`, and return the value of that property from `clientPortsList.SelectedValue`. With multi-select, that's not a real useful concept for you, and anyhow it's unrelated to the question you're asking here.

What you want to do is, for each `totalAvailablePorts` instance, bind the `isSelected` property of that instance to the `IsSelected` property of the `ListBoxItem` that owns it. You could do that with an item template, but a Style is much simpler (and better, if you aren't interested in recreating or altering the default `ListBoxItem` visual behavior). That answer is [already on StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1875450/binding-the-isselected-property-of-listboxitem-to-a-property-on-the-object-from):

```
<ListBox ItemsSource="..."
    x:Name="clientPortsList" 
    SelectionMode="Extended" 
    DisplayMemberPath="{Binding Path=portID}" >
  <ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
   <Style TargetType="{x:Type ListBoxItem}">
     <!-- binding totalAvailablePorts.isSelected to ListBoxItem.IsSelected -->
     <Setter Property="IsSelected" Value="{Binding isSelected}"/>
   </Style>
  </ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
 </ListBox>
```

For the `ListBoxItem` instances, their `DataContext` will be their respective `totalAvailablePorts` instances, so `isSelected` (lower-case I) will be "in scope".